# makefile.in error while building linphone on Xcode

Tags: xcode, terminal, makefile, linphone

I have a linphone source code downloaded from their website.I have followed the process which they have showed in  the Read Me file. Everything works well till I build, but when I give make all command, the following error is generated :

```
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: error: cannot find input file: `Makefile.in'
make[1]: *** [/Users/apple/linphone-iphone/submodules/build/../build-i386-apple-darwin/externals/polarssl/Makefile] Error 1
make: *** [broadcast_all] Error 2
```

These are the error lines which I come across. Need guidance on this. What could be going wrong here ? For your information, I am using osx 10.9 and Xcode 5.1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was building linphone-android and ran into the same 'Makefile.in' issue on my Mac OSX 10.8.5 in several submodules.  The thing to look for is in the submodule project's autogen.sh (in your case, submodules/externals/polarssl/autogen.h).  There it tries to set an environment var for the *libtoolize* tool.

```
if test -f /opt/local/bin/glibtoolize ; then
    # darwin
    LIBTOOLIZE=/opt/local/bin/glibtoolize
else
    LIBTOOLIZE=libtoolize
fi
```

I installed libtool (includes *libtoolsize*) via Mac Brew (package manager - [link](http://brew.sh)) and it found that I already had an Apple version of libtool at /usr/bin/libtool.  So it installed the Brew versions to /usr/local/bin/glibtool and glibtoolize.  I modified the above blocks of code in several submodule autogen.sh files to check /usr/local/bin/glibtoolize instead of /opt/local/bin/glibtoolize.

The other easier option that I'll probably go with if this build finishes for me, will be to just symlink /usr/local/bin/glibtoolize to /usr/bin/libtoolize - because on my system I don't have any Apple version of that one (only have Apple's libtool).